# Running IPython Notebook viewer locally

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to introduce IPython notebook in my work. One of the ways I want to do that is by sharing my own work as notebooks with my colleagues so they would be able to see how easy it is to create sophisticated reports and share them.

I obviously can't use Notebook viewer since most of our work is confidential. I'm trying to set up notebook viewer locally. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409774/is-it-possible-to-host-nbviewer-locally) and followed the instructions there, but now that nbconvert is part of IPython the instructions are no longer valid.

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

1. As described above convert to HTML and then serve them using a Simple server e.g python -m "SimpleHTTPServer" You can even set up a little python script that would "listen" in one directory. If changes or new notebooks is added to the directory the script will run nbconvert and move the HTML file to the folder you are serving from. To navigate to the server you are running go to yourip:port e.g. 10.0.0.2:8888 (see the IPython output when you run the IPython notebook command) (If you can serve over the network you might just as wel look into point 2 below)
2. If your computers are networked you can serve your work over the lan by sharing your IP address and port with your colleagues. This will however give them editing access but should not be a problem? This means that they will navigate to your ipython server and see the ipython notebook and be able to run your files.
3. Host your notebooks on an online server like Linode etc... entry level servers cheap. Some work is needed to add a password though.
4. Convert to PDF and mail it to them.
5. Convert to a slideshow (now possible in Version 1.00) and serve via option 1,2 or just share the HTML file with them.
6. Let them all run ipython notebook and check your files into a private repo at bitbucket (its free private git repo). They can then get your files there and run it themselves on their own machines.Or just mail it to them. Better yet if they wont make changes share a dropbox folder with everyone. If they run ipython notebook in that folder they will see your files (DANGEROUS though)
7. Get them in a boardroom and show them. :)