# Installing NBviewer on local computer And use it to view Notebooks from local network computer

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to introduce IPyhton notebook in my work. I want others colleagues in the local network to be able to see notebook Im sharing with them in their broswer or other solution.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572423/running-ipython-notebook-viewer-locally) question, I understood that the only solution I will be satisfied with would be viewing notebooks in nbviewer and not in HTML like solutions.

Question is, how doI install nbviewer and how do I set it up to accept viewing request in the LAN. the instructions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409774/is-it-possible-to-host-nbviewer-locally) are not working anymore since nbconvert is now a part of IPython and the code is no longer in github.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nbviewer could be installed locally same as before, it will just pick-up the nbconvert library from IPython 1.0 if it is installed on the same machine.

Supposing your ipynb are availlable on a local address, (Eg: `http://local-comany/foo.ipynb`) and nbviewer is hosted on (`http://local-nbviewer/`) then open the url `http://local-nbviewer/url/local-company/foo.ipynb` will work. (it will also work on notebook public on the internet)

The only requirement is that your nbviewer is hosted on a server that has access to the ipynb you like to share. For any url of type : `http://local-nbviewer/url/<something>.ipynb` nbviewr will try to fetch `http://<something>.ipynb` and render it.

Comment: Running python app.py from the command line returns an exeption on the following line of code: "from nbconvert.converters.template import ConverterTemplate". It seems it still looking for the nbconvert...

Comment: Are you using last version ? Try `python gist.py`

Comment: Can nbviewer open local files on the computer?

Comment: There are (or at least was) debug options to do so.

Comment: I recommend using the docker container at https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer. Took me 5 min to set up and works like a charm!